# Proving limit for multivariable function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to determine and prove the limit for the function $f(x,y) = \frac{x^3-x(y+1)^2}{x^2+(y+1)^2}$ for $(x_0,y_0)=(0,-1)$. Working with the equivalent (at least I think it is) limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^3-xy^2}{x^2+y^2}=L$,   I find that if such limit exists, then it must be $L=0$.

Now I think this is a situation where you have to apply the definition of limit to prove it, and this is where I get stuck. Looking at some examples it looks like I have to get to an expression that looks something like $|f(x,y)|<\delta$ where $\delta = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|\frac {x^{3}-xy^{2}} {x^{2}+y^{2}}|=(|x|)|\frac {x^{2}-y^{2}} {x^{2}+y^{2}}| \leq |x|$. It should now be clear that $\delta =\epsilon$ in the definition of limit will work.

Comment: This is probably a stupid follow up, but about your answer: is that true because $|\frac {x^{2}-y^{2}} {x^{2}+y^{2}}| \leq 1? $Also, following up on your solution is this  the right answer? $(|x|)|\frac {x^{2}-y^{2}} {x^{2}+y^{2}}| \leq |x| \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq \delta = \epsilon$

Comment: @paralaje Yes, you have understood the answer completely.